# How do I create a simple loop daemon bash script?

Tags: command-line, scripts, screen, services, screensaver

I want to create a simple daemon bash script that will run a command if my computer is inactive for more than 10 minutes. I created an alias to run a python script in the terminal, and I plan on using xprintidle to return the number of milliseconds the user has been idle. However, I have no knowledge of any kind of C, so I do not know how to make a daemon loop script. I would like, inside my loop, to:

1. Check if xprintidle returns more than 600,000 milliseconds
2. If so, then create a terminal window, and make it fullscreen, not maximized, but fullscreen(like F11)
3. Then, run the command **matrix**.

I do not want the script to suspend or end anything, I just want it to start a terminal screensaver.

If there is any chance I could use xscreensaver to monitor inactivity for me and run a bash script(which would not have to be automatically run at boot, and would most likely be shorter), that would be great, but I would still need the bash script.

Comment: I think this is on-topic at StackOverFlow, and off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go, it's pretty simple

```
#!/bin/bash

while [ 1 ]; 
do
  VALUE=$(xprintidle)
  if [ $VALUE -ge 600000  ];
  then
      gnome-terminal --full-screen -e 'matrix'
  fi
  sleep 0.25
done
```

Take the script above, save it in your personal `$HOME/bin` folder, as `gnome-terminal-screensaver.sh`. Make sure it is executable with `chmod +x $HOME/bin/gnome-terminal-screensaver.sh`. If you don't have one, create one. It is suggested to open `$HOME/.profile` and make sure that 3 lines bellow are uncommented:

```
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
#if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
#    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
#fi
```

Next, create `$HOME/.config/autostart/gnome-terminal-screensaver.desktop` file with the following contents

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=/home/username/bin/gnome-terminal-screensaver.sh
Terminal=false
```

*Remember to change /home/username to actual /home/username*

Comment: Thanks for your response. The bash script required a bit of tweaking:

#!/bin/bash

while [ 1 ]; 
do
  VALUE=$(xprintidle)
  if [ $VALUE -ge 600000 ] && [ $VALUE -le 605000 ];
  then
      gnome-terminal --full-screen -e '/home/frenebo/Documents/matrix.py'
  fi
  sleep 5
done

The screensaver restarted every time it cycled, so I did some minor research on bash scripting, and it works fine now.